# Why does selecting a real type only prints out max 6 digits in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, psql

I have a `Postgres` table which has a column of `real` type.

When I use a query in order to select the values from this column (e. g. `select amount from my_table`), it round the value for numbers larger than 100,000. (It completely ignores the decimal part). For numbers larger than 1,000,000, it displays them using the scientific notation. For numbers smaller than 100,000 it strips off the decimal part so that only 6 digits max are printed out overall (e. g. 1,000.12345 becomes 1,000.12).

It is only when I cast the value to double precision (using `CAST(amount as double precision)`) that it starts to behave as I'd expect and it prints out all the stored decimal digits.

Does anyone have an idea why is Postgres behaving in this manner?

Comment: You can simply find the explanation in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html): "real 4 bytes 6 decimal digits precision" and "double precision 8 bytes 15 decimal digits precision" It is same for most other programming language (it is HW floating point numbers representation actually) Use `numeric` data type instead.

Comment: As far as I understand 6 decimal digits means 6 digits *after* the decimal point. **Not** 6 digits overall

Comment: Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. 6 digits overall. At least per docs.

Comment: Simply. With 2 bytes it is possible to store maximum 65535 unsigned int or, say, 4 decimal digits (9999) because 5 decimal digits (99999) is overflow. Same with float: you need to store integer part + exponent value + sign bits for both in 4 bytes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: If this were true then using `CAST(amount as double precision)` would have no effect because only 6 digits would be stored in the `real` column in the DB, right? But it *has* effect hence I'm implying that the behaviour is related to actually *displaying* the number rather than *storing* it. Do you see my point?

Comment: It is impossible to display more then stored, right? :) Ok, I believed to the official documentation but after some quick experiments there is something interesting. Let me some time, I will inform you about results later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is likely in PostgreSQL source code **postgres/src/fe_utils/print.c**.
Comments for `format_numeric_locale` say:

```
/*
 * Format a numeric value per current LC_NUMERIC locale setting
 *
 * Returns the appropriately formatted string in a new allocated block,
 * caller must free.
 *
 * setDecimalLocale() must have been called earlier.
 */
```

See also comments in `setDecimalLocale`.

It's also possible that some reasons can be found in SQL standards.

Comment: Question is not related to the numbers formatting but to the machine representation of them IMO.

Comment: Yes. float - 6 digits precision and double - 15 digits precision. Everything with more  precision will be rounded to 6 (15) digits and represented in the scientific format. More, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: If this were the case I wouldn't even be able to store more than 6 digits in a DB column which type is `real`. But the problem arises only when I select the value from the DB

Answer (score 0):

OK but with PG 12.2 there are some formatting differences  between real and double precision:

```
# select x, x::double precision from t order by 1;
       x       |      x      
---------------+-------------
        123456 |      123456
        999999 |      999999
         1e+06 |     1000000
  1.000001e+06 |     1000001
  1.234567e+06 |     1234567
 1.2345671e+06 | 1234567.125
  1.234568e+06 |     1234568
  9.999999e+06 |     9999999
  9.999999e+06 |     9999999
         1e+08 |   100000000
 1.2345679e+09 |  1234567936
 1.2345679e+09 |  1234567936
(12 rows)
```

And it seems that you can have 7 decimal digits precision.